# How to include data-url-encode data using drupal_http_request()?

Tags: 7, database

I am attempting to make a GET request using `drupal_http_request()`. A basic request works as expected but I need to include extra data. The example provided to me uses curl and the [-G --data-urlencode](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) option as shown below. What is the correct way to implement this type of request using [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7)()?

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Header-Example: Header Data" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'include=gator' \
  https://example.com/1/endpoint
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--data-urlencode` just appends `?foo=bar` to the end of the URL (encoded of course); `drupal_http_request()` has no special handling for query strings, it parses them directly from the provided URL with `parse_url()`.

That said, this would be functionally equivalent:

```
$data = drupal_http_build_query(array('include' => 'gator'));
$url = 'https://example.com/1/endpoint?' . $data;
drupal_http_request($url);
```

Request from Drupal:

```
GET /1/endpoint?include=gator HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Drupal (+http://drupal.org/)
Host: example.com
```

Request from cURL:

```
GET /1/endpoint?include=gator HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: example.com
```